# Ansible: find and replace with remote IP

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am using Ansible for auto apache configuration in which i have own app.conf. Now I have app.conf in ansible server and want ansible to replace the existing ip address with remote ip address. my app.conf look like this.

```
<VirtualHost \
10.10.10.10:80 \
10.10.10.10:80 \
>
DocumentRoot /var/www/application/httpdocs
ServerName lists
ServerAlias lists.*
UseCanonicalName Off
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/
Alias /icons/ /var/www/icons/
Alias /pipermail/ /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/
<Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now I want 10.10.10.10 to be replaced by remote ip address. can we do this using lineinfile module.

```
lineinfile:
  path: /etc/hosts
  regexp: '^10\.10\.10\.10'
  line: ''
  owner: root
  group: root
  mode: 0644
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a template. I'll use below the default ipv4 address on the remote host. You can explore the gathered facts if you need something else. In a nutshell:

`templates/app.conf.j2`

```
<VirtualHost {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/application/httpdocs
ServerName lists
ServerAlias lists.*
UseCanonicalName Off
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/
Alias /icons/ /var/www/icons/
Alias /pipermail/ /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/
<Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then you playbook should look like

```yaml
- name: Configure my application
  hosts: my_hosts
  
  tasks:
    - name: deploy the configuration template
      template:
        src: app.conf.j2
        dest: path/to/app.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically this should be possible, but you will run into problems because:

> the pattern to replace if found; only the last line found will be replaced

[lineinfile module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html)

So if you want to change `/etc/hosts` that should be fine. If you want to change a configuration file with multiple occurances of the rexex pattern you will run into problems. (From the question it is unsure weather you want to change /etc/hosts or app.conf)

If you want to manage a apache configuration file you will be better of with the [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html)

Comment: I want to copy app.conf to remote server and change the existing ip address to remote address. Also whenever new changes is done on app.conf lets say "Document Directory" it would automatically sync to all server and change the ip address to remote address.